# Showing that a sequence (defined in terms of the previous sequence term) is increasing and bounded above

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, induction

I'm stuck on this problem and I was wondering if you would be kind enough to help. The question follows:

Let $x_{1} = 1$ and $x_{n}$ = $\sqrt{ 1 + 2x_{n-1}}$ for n $\geq$ 2. Show that the sequence $\left ( x_{n} \right )_{n \geq 1}$ is increasing and bounded above.

We were told to use induction for the bounded above proof, which I have completed already by assuming that 3 is an upper bound of a certain value and then changing around the equations to show that the following sequence term is smaller than 3 also, so, I think I am done with that.

However, I'm stuck on proving that it is increasing for all values of n. Would you be able to help?

Thanks!
Lauren

Comment: Use induction again keeping in mind that taking the square root doesn't change the order.

Comment: And if a limit $L$ exists, then $L=\sqrt{1+2L}$

Comment: I'm still not sure how I can use induction to show it. I have been trying for hours to get it now. Can someone help me get started with the induction?

Thanks!

Comment: You can prove that $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is increasing by induction.

The statement to prove is $\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(x_n\leq x_{n+1}\right)$.

For the inductive step take $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n\leq x_{n+1}$.

The thesis is now $x_{n+1}\leq x_{n+2}$.

Well
$$\begin{align}
x_{n+1}\leq x_{n+2}&\iff \sqrt{1+2x_n}\leq\sqrt{1+2x_{n+1}}\\
&\iff 1+2x_n\leq1+2x_{n+1},
\end{align}$$

because everything is positive.

After simplification one gets the inductive hypothesis and thus the thesis follows.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1+2x}$ then $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$ and since $f$ is an increasing function and $x_2>x_1$ then the sequence $(x_n)$ is increasing. Let $\ell=1+\sqrt 2$ the root greater than $1$ of the equation $f(x)=x$. Prove by induction that $x_n<\ell$.